# Numeric to alphanumeric encoder using python (permutation and regex)

Tags: python, regex, dictionary, permutation, encoder

Hello fellow stackers,

I'm facing problem that I hope you can help resolve.

I've written two pieces of code which I want to merge together.
Basically on given input of an numeric string, I want to iterate over each character in the string. The characters are analysed by the conditional statement and converted to another symbol e.g. numbers converted into letters, in essence i'm trying to create an encoder. Furthermore I need the flexibility to encode the numbers with different symbols e.g. the number zero to A or B and I want to compare the output lists so that I can permutate every possible combination.

Example:

Input
01
- 0 to A* 
- 0 to B*
- 1 to *C

Outputs
AC
BC

I've tried a few combinations so far and I think i'm over complicating things.

This first application iterates over the word-list and if the statement contains the numbers. Numbers which are irrelevant are "packed" with an asterix for use in the next stage of processing.

```
import re

wordlist = ["012"]

for i in range(0, 2):
    if i == 0:
        dictionary = ['A', 'B']
        for symbol in dictionary:
            for x in range(0, 1):
                zero = re.sub("0", symbol, wordlist[x])
                zero = re.sub("[1-9]", "*", zero)
                wordlist.append(zero)
    elif i == 1:
        dictionary = ['C']
        for symbol in dictionary:
            one = re.sub("1", symbol, wordlist[x])
            one = re.sub("[02-9]", "*", one)
            wordlist.append(one)

del wordlist[0]
print(wordlist)
```

The second application merges the two words together:

```
wordone = "A****"
wordtwo = "*B***"
# wordthree = "**C**"

union = []

for charA, charB in zip(wordone, wordtwo):
    enumerate(charA)
    asciicharA = ord(charA)
    enumerate(charB)
    asciicharB = ord(charB)

    if (asciicharA ^ asciicharB != 0):
        if (chr(asciicharA) == "*"):
            union.append(chr(asciicharB))
        elif (chr(asciicharB) == "*"):
            union.append(chr(asciicharA))
    elif (charA and charB == "*"):
        union.append(charA or charB)

print(union)
```

I can't seem to work out how to merge the two applications together. I believe I need to create the output of the first application into individual strings for post processing in the second application however I think there may be a far efficient way to produce the results I require.

Furthermore I believe there is a permutation function in the "itertools library" that I can take advantage to produce the results I require in the second application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for [**`itertools.product`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) in combination with list unpacking:

```
from itertools import product

# map every possible combination here
substitutes = {'0': ['A', 'B'], '1': 'C', '2': ['D', 'E', 'F']}

# the actual input
input = '012'

raw = [substitutes[char] for char in input]
for c in product(*raw):
    print(c)
```

Which yields

```
('A', 'C', 'D')
('A', 'C', 'E')
('A', 'C', 'F')
('B', 'C', 'D')
('B', 'C', 'E')
('B', 'C', 'F')
```

Comment: Wow absolutely fantastic! thank you for answering my question with some simple and excellent code!

Comment: @Manifesto: You're welcome. Really have a look at the `itertools`, they are powerful.